# How to create a published procedure/function in activeX with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, activex, publish

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't access public function in delphi ActiveX control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336129/cant-access-public-function-in-delphi-activex-control)

I'm working with an ActiveX control implement by Delphi. In my main class, I have:

```
  type
      TezDICOMX = class(TActiveForm, IezDICOMX)
        ToolBar1: TToolBar;
        OpenBtn: TSpeedButton;
        PreviousBtn: TSpeedButton;
```

....
I add these code to the class.

```
 published
procedure abc; safecall;
```

After that, I build the project and register the ActiveX server. It generate the ezDICOMax.ocx. I open the visual studio, delete the remain ezDICOM activeX control I've embed before and embed the new one. I drag the activeX control to the design and name it the_ezdicom. 
So as I think, I should can call the_ezdicom.abc(), but when I do that, the compiler complains

```
'AxezDICOMax.AxezDICOMX' does not contain a definition for 'abc' and no extension method 'abc' accepting a first argument of type 'AxezDICOMax.AxezDICOMX' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What I did wrong? How to create a published procedure/function in ActiveX control with Delphi? 
If I change an existing function/procedure in the class and do all the register, embed step, the result of that function/procedure when I call from C# change too, so I think that the activeX control is updated to my Delphi source, but I still can't add published procedure/function.

Comment: Did you edit the type library in delphi?

Comment: Yes, I did edit the type library, but it keep add the procedure abc to the protected area. So I just type it in published area. How to edit the type library to add an published? I use Delphi 7.

Comment: I did read from some website say use the Edit->Add to Interface. I use that with "procedure abc1". When I browse the source code, it's placed in public area. When I use the treeview, it also placed at public area, but still the same error from C# about abc1.

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

1. Edit the type library (using the type library editor) to add the new method
2. Refresh the implementation (this can be done automatically by the type library editor, depending on your IDE settings), write your implementation code in the generated method body
3. Build and re-register your ActiveX server (in case you added new interfaces or data types); run regsvr32 as administrator because it needs access to protected registry branches.

The Delphi visibility of the implementor method is irrelevant in this case: the class is supposed to be used through an interface pointer, not through a Delphi class instance pointer. Therefore I would recommend to keep it protected, as generated by the type library editor.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It gives me some points too.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is a problem with Visual Studio. Because I change the interface of my activeX control, so I have to delete the reference to activeX control in my project, add it again. If we do not change the interface, just unregister and register the activeX control is enough.